# Parse json string in web service

Tags: json

I want to parse JSON string.
Problem is with writing classes.how should i write classes like table structure or according to JSON string?

```
Format: JSON
    Content: 
    {
        success: 0,
        message: “”,
        token :””,
        data:
{
"User":{
                        "UserID": 1212,
                        "UserEmail": "abc@abc.com",
                        "UserNameLast": "abc",
                        "UserNameFirst": "xyz",
                        "UserRoleID": 1,
                        "UserRole": "Sales Executive",
                        "UserPhone": "1212",
                },
"Managers":[{
                            "UserID":1,
                            "UserEmail": "qwe@abc.com",
                            "LastName": "qwe",
                            "FirstName": "qwe",
                            "UserRole": "Manager",
                            "UserPhone": "222222",
                        },
        {
                            "UserID":2,
                            "UserEmail": "eee@abc.com",
                            "LastName": "eee",
                            "FirstName": "eee",
                            "UserRole": "General Manager",
                            "UserPhone": "33333",
                        }
]
}
}
```

Table structure is different than json string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go ahead and define a class based on the  JSON
say "Class User" and then have getters and setters for the class and then while parsing the JSON you can set the field of the class.

Comment: ok.but as shown in above json string i have insert 1record(User) in some table at the same time 2 records in another table(managers) for example 1 request send to its 2 manager.request table is different and request forwarded to table table is different.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need it into C# classes If yes then
Use http://jsonlint.com/ to check if it is valid Json then  http://json2csharp.com/ to convert it into C# classes.
I think it is easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

This is how your model should look like to be serialized in like the json you supplied.

```
 public class UserDetailViewModel
{
    public User User { get; set; }

    public List<Manager> Managers { get; set; }
}
```

And then return the object like `Json(userDetailViewModelInstance).`